# Adding external jar as dependency in maven project in Intellij IDE

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij community edition v2020.3.2 and Java 8.

I am adding external jar file by following steps, File -> ProjectStructure -> Project Settings -> Modules -> + -> Jars or Directories.

Execution works fine in IDE. But when install using maven throws an error "package package-name does not exist".

My pom.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>DDXUtils</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.ph</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ValidationManager</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.ph.validationManager.Dummy</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-libs</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/target/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-artifact</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

When I remove the external jar, the maven install works fine.

Comment: Dependencies need to be added by maven not your IDE, else your build doesn't know about them.

Comment: Yes, IDEs are great at breaking *de facto* standards such as Ant and Maven

Comment: @ M. Deinum Yeah I am doing that now. Thanks for reaching out.

Answer (score 1):

To use local jar with Maven you will first need to install this jar into your Maven local repository. Then you can specify it as a dependency in your Maven pom.xml build file and IDE will also link it automatically based on the Maven configuration. You can import it using similar command:

```
mvn install:install-file \
   -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
   -DgroupId=<group-id> \
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
   -Dversion=<version> \
   -Dpackaging=<packaging> \
   -DgeneratePom=true
```

See this answer:

***Warning**: never modify IDE project structure settings manually in Maven/Gradle based project - as IDE will reset this manual configuration after Maven/Gradle **Reload**.*

Comment: Yes, this seems to be Maven's specified way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I add the jars to the maven POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>FIRST_LIBRARY_ID</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>lib/my_lib_1.jar</file>
                        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>FIRST_LIBRARY_ID</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>SECOND_LIBRARY_ID</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>lib/my_lib_2.jar</file>
                        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>SECOND_LIBRARY_ID</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then Just add them to dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>FIRST_LIBRARY_ID</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>SECOND_LIBRARY_ID</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can put what you want in `<id>` tags, just every execution step must to have different ids.
The things happens into the `<configuration>` tag, insert your jar filename and the other values are custom, you only must to use the same `<groupId>` `<artifactId>` and `<version>` in the dependencies reference.

Comment: Seems OK, but isn't there a *slightly* less long-winded way by defining another repository location and then specifying dependencies? It would be tough adding an `<execution>` for every one of loads of local jars to add. btw, I didn't downvote this answer ;)

Comment: @g00se This is all I've found to add a jar as maven dependency, without to use your local .m2 repository or have a server with a maven repository somewhere